# what is cxid used for in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

in the zookeeper logs and also in source code i see there is a field named `cxid` in Request/Txn/Header.

```
2018-06-24 02:28:55,003 [myid:1] - DEBUG [CommitProcessor:1:FinalRequestProcessor@88] - Processing request:: sessionid:0x1642e63d6060000 type:ping cxid:0xfffffffffffffffe zxid:0xfffffffffffffffe txntype:unknown reqpath:n/a
```

i am not able to understand what it is used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cxid` is a monotonically increasing integer generated at the client just before the client sends a Packet to the server.

The below is an excerpt from zookeeper log which shows some create commands by three different sessions. As you can see below, the `cxid` is increasing for each new command from the same session.

```
7/2/18 10:52:06 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x0 zxid 0x100000021 createSession 30000

7/2/18 10:52:06 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x1 zxid 0x100000022 create '/data5,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,5

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x2 zxid 0x100000023 create '/data5/path1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x3 zxid 0x100000024 create '/data5/path1/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x4 zxid 0x100000025 create '/data5/path1/child2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x5 zxid 0x100000026 create '/data5/path2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x6 zxid 0x100000027 create '/data5/path2/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0004 cxid 0x7 zxid 0x100000028 create '/data5/path2/child2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:07 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x0 zxid 0x100000029 createSession 30000

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x1 zxid 0x10000002a create '/data6,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,6

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x2 zxid 0x10000002b create '/data6/path1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x3 zxid 0x10000002c create '/data6/path1/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x4 zxid 0x10000002d create '/data6/path1/child2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x5 zxid 0x10000002e create '/data6/path2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x6 zxid 0x10000002f create '/data6/path2/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:08 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0005 cxid 0x7 zxid 0x100000030 create '/data6/path2/child2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x0 zxid 0x100000031 createSession 30000

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x1 zxid 0x100000032 create '/data7,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,7

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x2 zxid 0x100000033 create '/data7/path1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x3 zxid 0x100000034 create '/data7/path1/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x4 zxid 0x100000035 create '/data7/path1/child2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x5 zxid 0x100000036 create '/data7/path2,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,2

7/2/18 10:52:09 PM IST session 0x1645c03e93f0006 cxid 0x6 zxid 0x100000037 create '/data7/path2/child1,#74686973,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1
```

The `cxid` is specific to connection, not session. So if a client abruptly disconnects from server and recconnects with previous `sessionid` , the `cxid` will start again i guess. not sure if this would cause any problem.

The `cxid` is generated in the class `org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn` in the method `org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.getXid()`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a client makes a connection to the zookeeper server a set of transaction starts between the two. Here two ids are maintained cxid and zxid.

cxid is an incremental sequence of numbers which represent the starting point of the session with the client.

Whereas zxid is the zookeepers transaction id and tracks any change which zookeeper handles.

cxid 0x0 zxid 0x20 createSession - this is the time when the client started the session with zookeeper

cxid 0x1 zxid 0x21 error

cxid 0x2 zxid 0x22 error

cxid 0x3 zxid 0x23 error

cxid 0x4 zxid 0x24 error

cxid 0x5 zxid 0x25 error

cxid 0x6 zxid 0x26 error

cxid 0x7 zxid 0x27 error

cxid 0x8 zxid 0x28 error

cxid 0x9 zxid 0x29 error

cxid 0xa zxid 0x2a error

cxid 0xb zxid 0x2b error

cxid 0xc zxid 0x2c error
cxid 0xd zxid 0x2d error

cxid 0x13 zxid 0x2e create

cxid 0x16 zxid 0x2f create

cxid 0x19 zxid 0x30 setData

cxid 0x20 zxid 0x31 setData

cxid 0x2d zxid 0x32 error

cxid 0x2f zxid 0x33 error

cxid 0x38 zxid 0x34 closeSession - session closed by the client

Answer (score -1):

> The **zxid** has **two** parts: the **epoch** and a **counter**. In our implementation
>   *the zxid is a 64-bit number. We use the high order 32-bits for the
>   epoch and the low order 32-bits for the counter.* Because it has two
>   parts represent the zxid both as a number and as a pair of integers,
>   (epoch, count). ***The epoch number represents a change in leadership.***
>   Each time a new leader comes into power it will have its own epoch
>   number. We have a simple algorithm to assign a unique zxid to a
>   proposal: the leader simply increments the zxid to obtain a unique
>   zxid for each proposal. Leadership activation will ensure that only
>   one leader uses a given epoch, so our simple algorithm guarantees that
>   every proposal will have a unique id.

Each **node** in a ZooKeeper namespace can have data associated with it as well as children. It is like having a file-system that allows a file to also be a directory. We use the term **znode** to make it clear that we are talking about ***ZooKeeper data nodes***.

When describing the ZooKeeper messaging protocol we will talk of packets, proposals, and messages:

> **Packet** a sequence of bytes sent through a FIFO channel
>
> **Proposal** a unit of agreement. Proposals are agreed upon by exchanging packets with a quorum of ZooKeeper servers. Most proposals
>   contain messages, however the NEW_LEADER proposal is an example of a
>   proposal that does not correspond to a message.
>
> **Message** a sequence of bytes to be atomically broadcast to all ZooKeeper servers. A message put into a proposal and agreed upon
>   before it is delivered.

As stated above, ZooKeeper guarantees a total order of messages, and it also guarantees a total order of proposals. ZooKeeper exposes the total ordering using a ZooKeeper transaction id (zxid). All proposals will be stamped with a zxid when it is proposed and exactly reflects the total ordering. Proposals are sent to all ZooKeeper servers and committed when a quorum of them acknowledge the proposal. If a proposal contains a message, the message will be delivered when the proposal is committed. Acknowledgement means the server has recorded the proposal to persistent storage. Our quorums have the requirement that any pair of quorum must have at least one server in common.

[Reference](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.2/zookeeperInternals.html)

Comment: thanks, i understand zxid. my question was about cxid as shown above in logs and also in zookeeper source code

Comment: (Sorry, I couldn't find much about cxid, all I can say is that it's used in datatxntree)

I searched for the particular issue you're facing and I found out that the main problem is: Ephemeral znode not deleted after session has expired on one follower. (quorum is in an inconsistent state). There is a patch available for it and I'm sharing it with you. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1453